# Why the Configuration and Dependency in Gradle are not ExtensionAware?

Tags: groovy, build, gradle

According to this page, 
http://gradle.org/docs/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.plugins.ExtensionAware.html

A lot of domain objects in Gradle are Extension aware, which means one can set extension properties on it by 
`ext.key = value`, or by other ways

The page says Configuration and Dependency are extension aware, and they should be, but they're not, 
not I can see.

Two pieces of evidence:

First, this code snippet should set a property on a dependency object

```
dependencies {
    testCompile(group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.9') {
        provided = true
        ext.provided = true
    }
}
```

But I cannot get the value from elsewhere.

```
task test  { task ->
    task.project.configurations.testCompile.each { 
        println it
        println it.provided
        println it.ext.provided
        println it.hasProperty('provided')
    }
}
```

Nothing shows up.

Although when i set `provided=true`, Gradle warns me that dynamic properties are deprecated, use extension property, which by the way, dynamic properties don't seem to work either.

Second, According to Gradle's source code,
the Configuration and Dependency object ARE NOT ExtensionAware.

https://github.com/gradle/gradle/blob/master/subprojects/core/src/main/groovy/org/gradle/api/artifacts/Dependency.java

So am I missing some points? Or this feature has not been implemented so far.
I think this is an important feature.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Configuration` and `Dependency` *are* `ExtensionAware`. The interface is added dynamically at runtime. `project.configurations.testCompile.each` iterates over the resolved files. To iterate over the declared dependencies, use `project.configurations.testCompile.(all)Dependencies.all`.

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is really old but I ran into this today working with copied and detached configurations which are not ExtensionAware even though I want them to be and thought they would based on the doc referenced in the OP's question. This turned up at the top of my google query, so I thought I would share in case anyone else runs accross this (not enough rep to reply to Peter Niederwieser's answer)...Peter, is this a bug (at least in the docs?)

```
$ cat build.gradle
apply plugin: 'base'

configurations {
    ericwashere
}

task test << {
    println configurations.ericwashere instanceof ExtensionAware
    println configurations.ericwashere.copy() instanceof ExtensionAware
    println configurations.detachedConfiguration() instanceof ExtensionAware
}


$ ./gradlew --version

------------------------------------------------------------
Gradle 2.11
------------------------------------------------------------

Build time:   2016-02-08 07:59:16 UTC
Build number: none
Revision:     584db1c7c90bdd1de1d1c4c51271c665bfcba978

Groovy:       2.4.4
Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.9.3 compiled on December 23 2013
JVM:          1.8.0_31 (Oracle Corporation 25.31-b07)
OS:           Windows 7 6.1 amd64


$ ./gradlew test
:test
true
false
false

BUILD SUCCESSFUL

Total time: 2.433 secs
```